# set color of triangle on run time

Tags: android, shapedrawable, android-shape

i am drawing a triangle with xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/rightArrow">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="87%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"  >
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="#000000"  />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

now i need to set the color of this triangle on run time, so i did

```
        LayerDrawable layers = (LayerDrawable)  this.getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drwable.customtriangle);  
       GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable)(ldrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.layerItemRightArrow));

shape.setcolor(mycolor);
```

but i am facing rotatedrwable can not be casted to gradientdrawble at

```
GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable)(ldrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.layerItemRightArrow));
```

i cant figure out how to procced...
Any help appreciated. 
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `getDrawable()` on the `RotateDrawable` to get at the `Drawable` that is being rotated.

Comment: This's a working solution. Thanks for your help. I spend a lot of time to find a solution.